# git push from remote server gives me authorization issue

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to push from my distant server...

I have a wordpress site, that I modified online, and now, a lot of css have been generated, and I need to include them into my git rep.

```
forge@ip-10-0-0-131:~/site.mx$ git push
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now, I read some [posts](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7235/missed-access-to-all-my-repositories-conq) that says it is different a ssh key and a deployment key, so I deleted my deployment key, and made sure my key was set in : Profile>Bitbucket Settings>SSH Keys

But now I have :

```
git push
conq: repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am a bit lost, what should I do???

Comment: Have you added `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` SSH key of `forge@ip-10-0-0-131` machine in your BitBucket Account?

Comment: Yep, when I try to add it in Profile>Bitbucket Settings>SSH Keys, it says I already have this key declared

Comment: ok. If you have `multiple BitBucket` account, and you added the `SSH` in another account (`different email`)  then add `another account username` as a contribution in this account.

Comment: use `GIT_SSH="ssh -vvv"` and post the output.

Comment: Well GIT_SSH="ssh -vvv" does not output anything. I have just 1 bitbucket account, But I used laravel forge initally, and I created a deployment key to enable autodeploy. Thing is I never wanted to push directly from remote server. The git user in config in remote server is a different email, yes.